# Plotting bar plots for categorical variables in STATA

Tags: dataframe, stata, analysis, categorical-data, impact-analysis

I have a survey data baseline and endline. I am trying to plot bar plot for qualification of the respondent in each group (baseline/endline).

I am using the following code:

```
 graph bar, over(qualification) over(time)
```

It is giving me different output from what I want.
[image: my output] I want the bars for endline and baseline for each category to be present parallel.

I am also attaching a reference picture to get the better idea about what I want.[image: output which I want]

Comment: It seems that you want percentages but are not asking for them in your syntax. Other than that, you don't give a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the `over` options of `graph bar` matters.

Consider this example:

```
clear
input x str1 a b
1 "a" 1
2 "a" 2
3 "b" 1
4 "b" 2
end

graph bar x, over(a) over(b) title("over(a) over(b)")
graph bar x, over(b) over(a) title("over(b) over(a)")
```

[image: example1]
[image: example2]

It looks like you need to swap the order of your `over` options.